# Performance differences between different ways of running a function

Tags: python, performance

I hope this is not a duplicate question.

I've run the same function in Python 3.4.2 in a **simple** way and in a **multi-processing** way and I've found that the simple way is faster. Perhaps my design is not good, but I don't see where the problem lies.

Below is my code:

**Common part**

```
import os
import math
from multiprocessing import Process
import timeit


def exponential(number):
    """
    A function that returns exponential
    """
    result = math.exp(number)
    proc = os.getpid()
```

**Simple solution**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    start = timeit.default_timer()
    numbers = [5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]

    for index, number in enumerate(numbers):
        exponential(number)

    stop = timeit.default_timer()
    duration = stop - start
    print(duration)
```

**Multi-processing solution**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    numbers = [5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
    procs = []

    for index, number in enumerate(numbers):
        proc = Process(target=exponential, args=(number,))
        procs.append(proc)
        proc.start()

    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()

    stop = timeit.default_timer()
    duration = stop - start
    print(duration)
```

What I see is that the simple solution is faster than the multi-processing one:

```
Duration with Simple solution:           2.8359994757920504e-05
Duration with Multi processing solution: 0.012581961986143142
```

Comment: There is overhead to setting up multiple processes. In this case, the simple solution is very quick, and switching to multiprocessing for such a small set size shows no benefit. As the length of numbers increases, it is *possible* that this would change.

Comment: Why use `enumerate()`? You never use the `index` variable, so you might as well just say `for number in numbers:`.

Answer (score 1):

Computing `math.exp(x)`, where x<100 (as it is in your case) is not especially difficult. So you don't computing these in parallel does not offer a clear advantage.

Remember that when you set up multiple processes, you also incur the overhead of creating a new process, and copying over the memory space, etc.

Finally, there's something to be said about you creating a new process for each number in that list. If that list had 100 numbers in it, you'd be creating 100 new processes, which will compete for time on your 4 or 8 cores (depending on your CPU), which will add to further delays (especially when the computation itself gets complex). You're better off creating a pool of processes and getting them to incrementally work on your dataset:

```
import math
import multiprocess as mp


def slave(qIn, qOut):
    for i, num in iter(qIn.get, None):
        qOut.put((i, math.exp(num))
    qOut.put(None)


def master():
    numbers = [5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]

    qIn, qOut = [mp.Queue() for _ in range(2)]
    procs = [mp.Process(target=slave, args=(qIn, qOut)) for _ in range(mp.cpu_count()-1)]
    for p in procs: p.start()
    for t in enumerate(numbers): qIn.put(t)
    for p in procs: qIn.put(None)

    answer = [None] * len(numbers)
    done = 0
    while done < len(numProcs):
        t = qOut.get()
        if t is None:
            done += 1
            continue

        i, e = t
        answer[i] = e

    for p in procs: p.terminate()
    return answer
```